# Rxjs repeat call until a value is found

Tags: angular, rxjs

In angular 8 I have a method that needs to keep repeating until i get a particular success message from the server.

In my webapi method it has a call that pings another server and the other server sends back an api key. I need to keep calling this method  until an api key is generated and finally sent back. This is the need for the retry interval.

My issue is the response == success call is never hit.

```
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get<any>(url)
        pipe(
        map(response => {
          if(response == 'Success'){   <--- Not getting hit.
              resolve(true);
          }
        }),
        timeout(500),           
        retry(),
        delay(1500),
        repeat());
    })
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is the primary task you want to achieve?

Comment: sorry updated the details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about your primary task but can definitely help you with the issues in code.

1. I don't think you need promises here. You can develop your code without them.
2. You need to subscribe to your observable in order to emit values from observable.
3. You need to use tap operator instead of map operator, as you need to check existence of value

   ```
   this.http.get<any>(url)
   pipe(
   tap(response => {
     if(response == 'Success'){   <--- Not getting hit.
       alert('successful data')
     }
   }),
   timeout(500),           
   retry(),
   delay(1500),
   repeat()).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
   })
   ```

Comment: I've used this and it works...it's possible to have an exaplanation on all the methods called after the if condition (timeout, retry, delay, repeat, etc...) 

It will help others to understand the concepts, more than doing just copy & paste! thanks :)

Comment: For this code. How to stop the repeat when success, and call next request/stream?

Answer (score 0):

If you checkout [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/retrywhen), I think you'll find an answer. I think this fits your question.

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.http.get<any>(url).pipe(
    tap(response => {
      if(response == 'Success'){   <--- Not getting hit.
        resolve(true);
      } else {
        // will be catch on retryWhen
        throw 'ERROR';
      }
    }),
    // if any errors, wait 1.5s and try again
    retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(delayWhen(_ => timer(1500)))
  ).subscribe();
});
```